# Is there (still) an outbound firewall for windows xp working as gateway? (2017)

Tags: networking, windows-xp

this will be a funny question for some and a "are you crazy" for others.

pre: my 10.1.1/24 network is marked as a "don't download it's a pay one"

Situation in a short:

I have my portable DMZ in form of a windows XP called "lady" an old Eee PC configured as gateway and and old WIFI router, so when my wife and I am traveling, the "lady" makes the connection to the local WIFI, and the old router makes the standard (for us) 10.10.1.1 network to connect private.

looks like this:

```
                    WIFI (168.169.z.1)
                            |
                    ladynet-out (168.196.z.DHCP)
                            |
                    ladynet-in (10.10.1.254/24)             
                            |
                    old WIFI router (10.10.1.254)
                        |     |       |
                    comp1   comp2   comp3
```

The logic is, that we can somehow save communicate within the 10.x.x.x network. Probably not the stone of wise, but works good.

Till now no question.

But these days (windows 10) all changed, windows 10 is hungry for network, and all browsers are, too (update, update, update)

My problem: I am traveling in countries, where many connections (WIFI) are not so good and handled with a "fair use" logic - means "if you download to much we turn of or reduce heavily"

So what happens:

power on: "lady" she plays internet radio too. all good

power on: "comp1" after 10 secs, radio is off, network overload ..., comp1 tries to get everything in internet

All are active, chrome, firefox, friends and so on

So I would like to put a Outbound Firewall to the old windows XP to stop this nonsense

Is there one? I could not find one

Comment: Windows Firewall functionality has remained unchanged between when it was first introduced Windows XP Service Pack 2 to the current release of Windows 10 ( i.e. Windows 10 Version 1703 ).

Comment: @Ramhound: :O I am just too stupid to handle it, and all the messages about "windows XP cant handle outgoing" are false? I cant wait to put my fingers on "lady" ok sounds bad but it's  not meant bad